# C# Dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#

I need the code to clear the dropdownlist text not item. Like `textbox1.text=" ";` please help me.

```
// I need dropdownlist clear like textbox.
TextBox1.Text = ""; //like this
```

Comment: Please lay out your code properly so it's easier to see.

Comment: Please format your code in future.

Comment: What's your question? What's the problem wit the code that you have so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: DropDownList.SelectedValue = string.Empty;

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you have an empty-entry (name-value) to the DropDownList at 0 (1st) index.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Value="0">***Select***</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="10">Foo</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="20">Bar</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and use DropDownList1.SelectedIndex or SelectedValue property to reset the ListItem.

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue="0";
```

Comment: but and i have another question to friend, if the data bind from the dropdownlist in the sense what should we do for that

Comment: @AravindSai -Yes you can. After binding the DropDownList, insert a new ListItem at 0 index.

Comment: i didnt get the answer friend

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ...

```
MyDropDownList.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.